# Move WinForm some controls to another WinForm using partial classes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, partial-classes

I have a WinForm which has many panels, and each panel has many controls, which make it very hard to handle the design of this form, how to move each panel to a new form and return all panels to the main form at runtime?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What is the main reason for wanting to move controls between forms?

Comment: You can make each panel a user control and add them to your form.

Comment: the main form has much many panels and controls, and it's so hard to work with them Ben

Answer (score 3):

Creating a `UserControl` will help modularize your user interface. You should create one user control per panel let's say and then use those user controls in your form.

> The nice thing about `UserControl` is that they are reusable and can
>   be designed (visually) just like the Forms are designed.

You can refer to this below link to know more about `UserControls` for `WindowsForms`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx